# Is it possible to mix MooTools with Prototype and JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mootools, prototypejs

There are some things accross these which I'd like to use. I hope they've choosen clever naming conventions to prevent collisions with all their functions and classes? Does anyone use all these at once in one site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst it can be done (with `noConflict`), there are still potential conflicts.

For example jQuery adds a unique ID to element nodes it touches, which it expects to manage. If you remove such elements through a means other than jQuery you can get a memory leak; if you clone them from another framework (or DOM calls), you can confuse jQuery with subtle and weird results. There are also many potential interactions between the event models of the frameworks, especially `live` in jQuery.

If you keep the elements touched by each framework entirely separate, you might be able to get away with it. But really, I wouldn't recommend it. If at all possible, keep the number of frameworks used by your pages between zero and one.

Comment: +1 great, great answer. I didn't realize the potential problems go this deep.

Comment: honestly, I expected just that ;) ...big problems. oh man. too bad. it's like you have to choose between wearing only a left sock, or a right sock. What's better? Gonna spend days on that decision.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use mootools and jquery together, or jquery and prototype together simply by using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).  Using all three together might be a stretch as I don't believe that Prototype and Mootools have a no conflict mode and both define `$`.  However, there is [this article](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/) that talks about using `$` safely in Mootools, which might be able to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Mootools and Prototype both extend native javascript objects such as `String` and `Array`. I don't think there is any way you can make both of them work together without some conflict.

However, jQuery defines only a single global `$` object which it can let go if you use the `noConflict` mode. You'd then be using the `jQuery` object.

Comment: they've got obviously a great design!